# Grouping and Summing two different columns based on different conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario here. I have a function that correctly calculates the value for the Non_CombinedSet column. The condition for this Non_CombinedSet using case statement to group and count based on certain conditions. (Please see codes below:

```
   --Table creation
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testrun](
    [ProcessName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProcessMEMid] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProcessID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProcessSequence] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProcessSheets] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProcessMABSW] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY

--insert statement
INSERT INTO [dbo].[testrun]
           ([ProcessName]
           ,[ProcessMEMid]
           ,[ProcessID]
           ,[ProcessSequence]
           ,[ProcessSheets]
           ,[ProcessMABSW])

            VALUES 
                   ('A1','01-01','X1','1','3','M'),
                   ('B2','01-01','X1','5','2','M'),
                   ('C3','01-02','X1','6','4','M'),
                   ('D4','01-02','X1','10','8','M'),
                   ('E5','01-03','X1','30','18','M'),
                   ('F6','01-03','X1','25','25','M'),
                   ('G7','01-03','X1','50','30','M'),
                   ('H8','01-03','X1','25','15','M'),
                    ('I9','01-04','X1','15','10','M'),
                    ('J10','01-04','X1','15','3','M'),

                   ('K11','01-05','X1','10','2','M'),

                   ('L12','01-05','X1','05','15','M'),

                   ('M13','01-06','X1','05','11','M'),

                   ('N14','01-06','X1','05','13','M'),

                   ('O15','01-01','X1','05','50','M'),
                    ('P16','01-07','X1','05','7','M'),
                     ('Q17','01-07','X1','05','2','S'),
                      ('R18','01-07','X1','05','1','S'),
                       ('S16','01-08','X1','05','7','S'),
                        ('T16','01-08','X1','05','7','S')



--Function Creation
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_HIC_6] 
(   
@ProcessID VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    WITH CTE_Temp AS (
    SELECT 
       ProcessName =    
       CASE 
          WHEN ProcessSheets >=  1 AND ProcessSheets <=  5 THEN '1of'
          WHEN ProcessSheets >=  6 AND ProcessSheets <= 10 THEN '2of'
          WHEN ProcessSheets >= 11 AND ProcessSheets <= 16 THEN '3of'
          WHEN ProcessSheets >= 17 AND ProcessSheets <= 50 THEN '4of'
          WHEN ProcessSheets >  50   THEN '5of'
       END
       , ProcessMABSW
       ,ProcessID
       ,[ProcessMEMid]    
    FROM [dbo].[testrun]
)
SELECT  ProcessName = CASE WHEN GROUPING(ProcessName) = 0 THEN ProcessName ELSE 'Total' END 
       --,Combined_Set  = COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN ProcessMABSW = 'M' THEN [ProcessMEMid]  END))
     ,Combined_Set     = COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessMABSW = 'M' THEN ProcessMABSW   END)
    , Non_CombinedSet = COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessMABSW  <> 'M' THEN ProcessMABSW  END)
FROM CTE_Temp
WHERE ProcessID=@ProcessID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (ProcessName, ())


)
```

However, for the Combined_Set column, I am unable to correctly calculate what I am looking for. In isolation, I can easily get the correct result. Please see code below:

```
--Combined_Set 
WITH CTE_TEMP
AS
(

SELECT 
     [ProcessMEMid],Sum(isNULL(Cast([ProcessSheets] as int),0))  Combined
      ,COUNT([ProcessMEMid]) AS 'Total'
     FROM [dbo].[testrun]
     WHERE [ProcessID]='X1'
     AND [ProcessMABSW]='M'
     GROUP BY
        [ProcessMEMid]


)SELECT    
       CASE 
          WHEN Combined >=  1 AND Combined <=  5 THEN '1of'
          WHEN Combined >=  6 AND Combined <= 10 THEN '2of'
          WHEN Combined >= 11 AND Combined <= 16 THEN '3of'
          WHEN Combined >= 17 AND Combined <= 49 THEN '4of'
          WHEN Combined >  49   THEN '5of'
          --WHEN Combined >=1 AND Combined > 49 THEN CAST([Total] as varchar(10))
          ELSE CAST([Total] as varchar(10))
       END
       ,
       COUNT([ProcessMEMid]) AS 'Combined'
FROM  CTE_TEMP
GROUP BY 
CASE 
          WHEN Combined >=  1 AND Combined <=  5 THEN '1of'
          WHEN Combined >=  6 AND Combined <= 10 THEN '2of'
          WHEN CombIned >= 11 AND Combined <= 16 THEN '3of' 
          WHEN Combined >= 17 AND Combined <= 49 THEN '4of'
          WHEN Combined >  49   THEN '5of'
          --WHEN Combined >=1 AND Combined > 49 THEN CAST([Total] as varchar(10))
          ELSE CAST([Total] as varchar(10))
          END 

UNION 


    SELECT 
      CASE 
          WHEN 1=1 THEN 'Total'
          WHEN 2=2 THEN 'Total'
          WHEN 3=3 THEN 'Tota'
          WHEN 4=4 THEN 'Total'
          WHEN 5=5 THEN 'Total'
          END 
      ,COUNT(distinct [ProcessMEMid]) AS 'Total'
     FROM [dbo].[testrun]
     WHERE ProcessID='X1'
     AND ProcessMABSW='M'
```

The above returns the correct value. My question now is how do I incorporate Combined_Set query into my function (this portion of code `Combined_Set     = COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessMABSW = 'M' THEN ProcessMABSW   END)`

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I have understood is that you want to combine both the parts of your code into one function. Let me know if the below mentioned function works for you.You can do tweaks in the function below as per your needs:

```
alter function testfn(@processid as varchar(100))
returns table
as
return
(
with cte1 as
(
select isnull(cast(case   
            when ProcessSheets between 1 and 5 then '1of'
            when ProcessSheets between 6 and 10 then '2of'
            when ProcessSheets between 11 and 16 then '3of'
            when ProcessSheets between 17 and 50 then '4of'
            when ProcessSheets > 50 then '5of' 
       end as varchar(100)),'Total') as processname,
       count(case when processmabsw = 'M' then 1 end) as combined_set,
       count(case when processmabsw <> 'M' then 1 end) as noncombined_set,
       processid
from testrun
group by 
        grouping sets(case   
            when ProcessSheets between 1 and 5 then '1of'
            when ProcessSheets between 6 and 10 then '2of'
            when ProcessSheets between 11 and 16 then '3of'
            when ProcessSheets between 17 and 50 then '4of'
            when ProcessSheets > 50 then '5of' 
       end,()),processid
),cte2 as 
(
select processmemid,sum(cast(processsheets as int)) as combined,count(processmemid) as total,processid
from testrun
where processmabsw = 'm'
group by processmemid,processid
),cte3 as
(
select isnull(cast(case
            when combined between 1 and 5 then '1of'
            when combined between 6 and 10 then '2of'
            when combined between 11 and 16 then '3of'
            when combined between 17 and 49 then '4of'
            when combined > 49 then '5of'
       end as varchar(10)),'Total') as processname,count(ProcessMEMid) as combined,processid
from cte2      
group by 
        grouping sets(case
            when combined between 1 and 5 then '1of'
            when combined between 6 and 10 then '2of'
            when combined between 11 and 16 then '3of'
            when combined between 17 and 49 then '4of'
            when combined > 49 then '5of'
        end,()),processid
)
select a.processname,a.combined_set,a.noncombined_set,b.combined from cte1 as a
left join cte3 as b
on a.processname = b.processname
where a.processid = @processid

)
go

select * from testfn('x1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :-

```
SELECT  ProcessName = CASE WHEN GROUPING(ProcessName) = 0 THEN ProcessName ELSE 'Total' END 
        ,Combined_Set     = CASE WHEN ProcessMABSW = 'M' THEN COUNT(ProcessMABSW) ELSE 0   END
        , Non_CombinedSet = CASE WHEN ProcessMABSW  <> 'M' THEN COUNT(ProcessMABSW) ELSE 0  END
FROM CTE_Temp
WHERE ProcessID=@ProcessID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (ProcessName, ())
```

Comment: hanks but it didnt work. Keep in mind the logic of Combined_Set and Non_CombinedSet are quite different. The former groups, sums then count based on condition(Please see the code that explains it above) while the latter groups and count on a certain condition. –

Comment: any thoughts from anyone?